# Can .NET detect "irrelevant" code at runtime and garbage-collect objects in it?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, garbage-collection

Suppose I have a C# method like this

```
public void foo(){
    Object very_large_object;
    if (very_large_object.some_runtime_condition ()) {
        do_something ();
        return;
    }
    do_something_else (very_large_object);
}
```

In my case, `do_something` is an expensive method and may take some time to finish. When it's running, can .NET GC detects that `do_something_else` won't be called and thus `very_larget_object` is no longer relevant and garbage-collects it?

Comment: What about instantiate very_large_object only _after_ the if clause, so you instantiate it only if needed?

Comment: @GianPaolo Seems like I've oversimplified my code... The condition actually depends on `very_large_object`. But I guess I should set it null just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. It's a common misconception that object lifetime is somehow related to the enclosing scope (for example that `very_large_object` can only be collected when `foo` scope ends). You can verify your particular case with simple application:

```
class Program {        
    static void Main() {
        var o = new TestObject();
        var test = Console.ReadKey();
        if (test.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) {
            DoSomething();               
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        DoSomethingElse(o);
    }

    static void DoSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine("doing something");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("GC ran");
    }

    static void DoSomethingElse(TestObject o) {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}

public class TestObject {
    public TestObject() {

    }
    ~TestObject() {
        Console.WriteLine("finalizer running");
    }
}
```

If you compile that in Release mode with optimizations enabled, it will output the following (after you press Enter in console):

```
doing something
finalizer running
GC ran
```

So it's clear that `o` was considered garbage and was put into finalizer queue while we were still inside `DoSomething` method. Optimizer could not just throw away branch with `DoSomethingElse` because it depends on your console input whether it will run or not. If you remove `return` then of course it won't be collected.